# Overwrite ctrl+p in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am unable to overwrite `ctrl+p` in IE-11. Please Suggest something. I already tried from below code snippet .But, Its not working

Code to prevent default action

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {

        event.cancelBubble = true; 
        event.returnValue = false; 
        event.keyCode = 0;
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
           return false;
    }
```

Its working in compatibility mode on. When compatibility mode is off , then its not working . Please suggest solutions of it.

Comment: Don't mess with a browser's native functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen for Ctrl-P key press in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517819/how-to-listen-for-ctrl-p-key-press-in-javascript)

Comment: it seems IE11 doesn't allow developers to disable default behavior of certain native key bindings.  there is a similar thread about Ctrl+O http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083984/can-not-disable-ctrlo-by-javascript-in-ie-11

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
 if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you your replying.  i have tried this also. But, its not working. :(